# unordered_set c++

Tags: c++, memory, unordered-set

I've noticed that when I use an unordered set `unordered_set<int> theSet;` to hold large number of integers, it doesn't free the memory even with calls to clear() or rehash(0). Even if I defined the set locally in a function, and the function finished execusion, the most of the memory reserved by the set is still reserved. Any ideas?

Below is a sample code, when the tester function returns and we are in main, the memory
used by tester is not freed

Thanks

```
using namespace std;
using std::tr1::unordered_set;

void tester() {
    mySet.rehash(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        mySet.insert(i);

    mySet.clear();
}

int main() {
    tester();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you measuring memory consumption?

Comment: This kind of question should have a code snippet attached to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: The standard doesn't require that `clear` or `rehash` free anything. `clear` is required to call destructors of all elements and to leave the set in an "empty" state, but that doesn't mean it has to release backing memor. Similar is true for rehashing. Insofar, whether or not this happens, I don't consider it a problem. Popping elements off a `vector` usually doesn't free anything either. Nobody would consider that problematic.

Comment: `top` doesn't measure what you think it measures.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/swap) with a temporary set.

```
std::unordered_set<MyType> mySet;

// do stuff with mySet

std::unordered_set<MyType>().swap( mySet );
```

But your second claim doesn't make any sense. If you've declared a set local to a function, all memory used by that set will be released when the function exits.

Answer (score 1):

> I use top on unix

What probably happens is that memory does get released into the heap. However, the heap is not shrunk and the memory is not released back to the OS. Thus `top` is not showing any reduction in memory consumption.

If you were to re-create the `unordered_set` after destroying the first one, you probably wouldn't see an increase in memory consumption as measured by `top`.

When the process terminates, all its resources will be reclaimed.

Comment: But once the program terminates, the memory immediately drops!

Comment: @user1785771: Yes. When the process terminates, all its resources are reclaimed.